# Creating an emoji button like whatsapp for an ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am working on an Ionic app and I wanted to know, if it is possible to create an emoji button similar to whatsapp for an ionic app.

Comment: I'm happy to help if I can, but I don't use What's App. Is there a screenshot you can link to?

Comment: Hello @warcoder i am also working on same-thing so have you found any solution , as i am getting some issues while implementing.I am taking reference from  https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup.

Comment: any luck with this? i'm looking one for the ionic2 version

Answer (score 1):

there is something called @ionic-tools/emoji-picker

you can install it in your app

```
npm i @ionic-tools/emoji-picker --save
```

then import in you app module and your child page and use it like

```js
toggled: boolean = false;
emojitext: string;
 
handleSelection(event) {
  this.emojitext = this.emojitext + " " + event.char;
}
```

```html
<ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="emojitext"></ion-textarea>
 
<button ion-button clear icon-only (click)="toggled = !toggled" [(emojiPickerIf)]="toggled" [emojiPickerDirection]="'top'"
      (emojiPickerSelect)="handleSelection($event)">
      
</button>
```

[@ionic-tools/emoji-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-tools/emoji-picker)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an npm package for Ionic 4 & Ionic 5. https://github.com/Pankaj-Sati/ionic4-emoji-picker. Features:

1. Slider like interface (Like WhatsApp & any other chat app)
2. Modal Support. Open Emoji Picker in a modal
3. Easy styling